# Seeking Advice on Incorporating Online Discussions into Course Grading

Tags: grading, assessment

I've been utilizing edstem.org for facilitating math and logistics discussions in my course. Its support for LaTeX and hand-drawn illustrations has been convenient. Typically, students post questions, and I respond, though occasionally, some students also participate in discussions.

I'm contemplating integrating these online discussions into the grading system, specifically allocating 1% of the total grade to students who contribute two accepted answers. My goal is to encourage more engagement and collaborative learning.

However, I'm concerned this might lead to an influx of low-quality, or "fake," questions and answers from students aiming merely to secure the points.

Has anyone implemented a similar grading policy? What were your experiences?

Comment: Discussion points for online discussions never worked well for me. Your situation is different, but I wouldn't expect 1% to motivate, and it doesn't seem worth the effort.